# AngularJS Opening PDF in New tab

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS. I need help to get out of the below situation mentioned. I am trying to open an PDF file in new tab on button click. The code i am working around is below. The new tab does not open up. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

```
$http.get('/api/services/downloadpdf/' + scope.invoice.id, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function (response) {
    var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    file.name = 'invoice.pdf';
    var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $window.open(fileUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have file link just give like this, In html

```
<a target="_target" href="invoice.pdf" role="button">View</a>
```

In controller use this

```
$http.get('/api/services/downloadpdf/' + scope.invoice.id, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function (response) {
    var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    file.name = 'invoice.pdf';
    var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $window.open(fileUrl, '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code

```
var fileName = response.headers('content-name');
var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
linkElement.setAttribute("download", fileName);

var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
      "view": window,
      "bubbles": true,
      "cancelable": false
});
linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```